# Using microsoft speech recognition, could I get the time when half of the grammar has been recognized?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I want to use the grammar like this: **This is + name**.

The code is :

```
GrammarBuilder grammar = new GrammarBuilder();
grammar.Append("This is");
gammar.Append(new Choices("Bangalore", "Sanjay", "Cindy",...));
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grammar));
```

My question is, could I send the event when the engine recognize **This is**, and send another event when the engine recognize the name?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do this by using phrases

```
GrammarBuilder thisIsPhrase = new GrammarBuilder("This is");
Choices choices = new Choices("Dog, Cat");
GrammarBuilder endPhrase = new GrammarBuilder(choices);
Choices both = new Choices(new GrammarBuilder[] { thisIsPhrase, endPhrase });
Grammar dictationGrammar = new Grammar((GrammarBuilder)both);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder(v=office.14).aspx).

I haven't been able to test it yet though.

**Update:** the choices phrase doesn't seem to work.

```
GrammarBuilder thisIsPhrase = new GrammarBuilder("This is");
GrammarBuilder endPhrase = new GrammarBuilder("Dog");  //repeat creating phrases
Choices both = new Choices(new GrammarBuilder[] { thisIsPhrase, endPhrase });//also need to add phrases here
Grammar dictationGrammar = new Grammar((GrammarBuilder)both);
```